# Angular2 app - Remove Render-Blocking JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, angular, performance-testing

I have an angular2 firebase app.

I've noticed that when live it task 4 seconds to get 12 JavaScript libraries that I store locally in my prod build and then it shows the app.

**I need to get this 4 second delay down to 2 seconds.**

When I watch the sources in the console in chrome it just pauses for 4 seconds then loads. It seems to be render blocking JavaScript the correct term?

**Things I've tried:**

- HTML5 **async** and **defer** on the 12 JavaScript  libraries.
- I tried combining the libraries into the same file but that gave me loads of errors.
- My CSS is fine and all minified.
- All the js 12 files are minified.
- The 12 JavaScript libraries are all stored locally and not requested from other servers.
- I have images on my website and they are all optimized and compressed and placed on a CDN.

  - I use cloudflare and all the performance toggles are on.
  - I host with Firebase.
  - The JavaScript files are below the  and not in the header.

**My PageSpeed Insights scoress from google:**
(Resource: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

- 61/100 for mobile.
- 83/100 for desktop.

I can't use webpack.

I just want an easy method for showing the user interface and then load the libraries.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 generates your user interface, so what you are asking seems impossible at first. But you are in luck: the angular 2 team is working on something to help you out. It is actually already ready to use, but i don't think you can use it in combination with Firebase hosting. Take a look at https://universal.angular.io/. It allows you to render the initial view on the server side.